# Compiling cyrus-imapd

Tags: debian, installation, cyrus

When I run the make of *cyrus-imapd-2.4.17-caldav-beta9* get the following error:

```
In file included from httpd.c:68:0:
httpd.h:48:25: fatal error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I'm trying to install this beta version that supports calendars.

I have installed libxml2-dev.

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

My operating system is Debian 7.

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg -L libxml2-dev | grep tree.h` shows that libxml/tree.h is in /usr/include/libxml2, not /usr/include.  So you probably need to add `-I/usr/include/libxml2` to your compiler commands.  I don't know that particular Makefile, but typically you'd do that by running

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 ./configure
```

or

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 make
```